# Android Studio - Basic activity turns into empty activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

In Android Studio, when **creating** new **basic activity** and when clicked Finish, it didn't create a basic activity but just **empty activity**.

I don't have idea what's wrong with my project settings because I didn't change anything *(just moving package from one to another)*.

**In my other Android projects, there's no such bug and I can create basic activity.**

[image]

Comment: Did you check the name of the basic activity that you are creating! Make sure you are referring the right activity

Comment: @shadygoneinsane Yes the name and everthing is right. Even when i didn't change anyhting and use default title like mainactivity, and when i clicked finish it create empty/blank activity instead of basic activity.

Comment: if you have checked "use fragment" option your studio will end up showing the empty fragment and not your activity.. look for your activity... you will find your appbarlayout and fab and other stuffs there..

Comment: @Kannan_SJD I don't check anything, it's default basic activity. Please refer to the image provided.

Comment: @KapocsZoltan are you looking at activity_main2? or content_main2? also check your preview panel if you could see the app bar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to lower your API below 28 until this activity is working correctly.